# Datetime form with text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

Is there a way to have a text_field just for the date part of a datetime attribute?  For example, I have a datetime parameter called published_on, and I'd like my text_field to only submit for the date of the datetime field (not the time).  This didn't work:

```
<%= f.text_field :published_on, :value=> (@step.published_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")), :ignore_time=>true %>
```

and submits the parameter published_on rather than published_on(1i), published_on(2i), and published_on(3i) (for the year, hour, and minute).

**Edit**

I'm able to get the parameters now, but I have a time zone error

This is my controller code:

```
date = params[:step][:published_on]
logger.debug "date: #{date}"
time = params[:step][:"published_on(4i)"] +":" + params[:step][:"published_on(5i)"]
logger.debug "time: #{time}"
dateTime = date+ " " + time
logger.debug "dateTime: #{dateTime}"
dateTime = DateTime.strptime(dateTime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
logger.debug "datetime: #{dateTime}"

params[:step][:published_on] = dateTime

params[:step].delete :"published_on(4i)"
params[:step].delete :'published_on(5i)'
```

which prints the following log statements:

```
date: 01/01/2013
time: 00:00
dateTime: 01/01/2013 00:00
datetime: 2013-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

It seems like the time is incorrect since the timezone is set to the default (00:00).  Is there any way to get the timezone passed from the form?

Answer (score 1):

In your form, use the text_field without the :value option.

In your controller, try:

```
@your_model.published_on = DateTime.parse( params[:published_on] )
```

This will set the date, and leave the time-portion as 00:00 midnight

Comment: thanks for your help!  I'm getting an "invalid date" error when I try to parse the published_on parameter.  this is my controller code:
    @step.published_on = DateTime.parse(params[:step][:published_on]).  this is my form: <%= f.text_field :published_on, :ignore_time=>true %>

Comment: what string do you enter in the text_field? e.g.  `DateTime.parse("1/2/2013")
=> Wed, 02 Jan 2013 00:00:00 +0000` works for me. You might want to add extra validations, to make sure the data in the text field has a valid format that is recognized by `parse`

Comment: works for me: `DateTime.parse("05/31/2013")
=> Fri, 31 May 2013 00:00:00 +0000` -- maybe double check your log what string you get in the params

Comment: it's not working for me, unfortunately.  this is what I see in my logs:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2GpJDz9U0g1dHucOE1J2V9NIe/TFno1si+Ucz/cVSlE=", "step"=>{"description"=>"<p>Project description</p>\r\n", "published_on"=>"05/26/2013", "published_on(4i)"=>"00", "published_on(5i)"=>"01"}, "commit"=>"Update Step", "project_id"=>"92", "id"=>"0"}.  also, I don't want to overwrite the time to 00:00 so I tried combining it with my form time_select parameters.

Comment: well, you have nested forms! :) Your text_field is inside another form. This will fix it:  @your_model.published_on = DateTime.parse( params[:step][:published_on] )

Comment: ok, I almost have it.  the issue I'm having now is that it seems like it defaults to the wrong time zone: dateTime: 01/01/2013 00:00
datetime: 2013-01-01T00:00:00+00:00.  So when the user enters in the date, it's not correct.  Is there an easy way to get the right time zone?  thanks so much for your help!

Comment: you can attach the timezone to the date which you got from the user, e.g. params[:step][:published_on] + ' PDT'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have a text_field in the view?

As far as I can tell, you can have a date_time field and then just use two different input fields to set the different parts of the field.

```
form_for @event do |f|
  f.date_select :starts_at
  f.time_select :starts_at, :ignore_date => true
  f.submit
end
```

Since the rails date and time select helpers set five different parameters (starts_at(1i) for the year part, 2i for the month part, and so on), that means that the date_select only sets them for the date part, while if you pass :ignore_date => true to the time_select, it will only set the hour and minute part.

If you must have a text_field I'm not sure how to do it, but it might be possible to do using some jQuery magic before setting the datetime parameters before sending the form.

Comment: I wanted to use a text_field so the user can select the date from a datepicker, which I think is a nicer ui than a drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out thanks to a lot of Tilo's help.

This is what I have for my form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@project, @step], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do%>
        <%= f.text_field :published_on, :value=> (@step.published_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")), :ignore_time=>true %>  at <%= f.time_select :published_on, :class=>"btn dropdown-toggle", :ampm=> true, :ignore_date=>true %>
          <%= f.input :timeZone, :as=> :hidden, :value=> @step.published_on.zone%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and my controller:

```
 def update
    @step = @project.steps.find_by_position(params[:id])
    @step.images.each do |image|
      image.update_attributes(:saved => true)
    end
    date = params[:step][:published_on]
    logger.debug "date: #{date}"
    time = params[:step][:"published_on(4i)"] +":" + params[:step][:"published_on(5i)"]
    logger.debug "time: #{time}"
    timeZone = params[:step][:timeZone]
    logger.debug "timeZone: #{timeZone}"
    dateTime = date+ " " + time +" " + timeZone
    logger.debug "dateTime: #{dateTime}"
    dateTime = DateTime.strptime(dateTime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %Z')
    logger.debug "datetime: #{dateTime}"

    params[:step][:published_on] = dateTime

    params[:step].delete :"published_on(4i)"
    params[:step].delete :'published_on(5i)'
    params[:step].delete :timeZone

    respond_to do |format|
      if @step.update_attributes(params[:step])
        format.html { redirect_to project_steps_path(@project), :notice => 'Step was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @step.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

It seems sketchy to define a bunch of parameters for the same object and delete them later, but I didn't know any other way around it.